# Passing dynamic parameters in FOREACH loop in JSTL in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am displaying certain record on a jsp page using a FOREACH loop. it takes parameters begin and end. i want to pass dynamic parameters in them
like this:

```
<%! int i=5; int j=10; %>
<c:ForEach var="ad" item="Products" begin="i" end="j">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>${ad.id}</td>
            <td>${ad.name}</td>
         </tr>
     </table>
```

Comment: Use request attributes with EL. But this seems like a bad idea. Your logic should be in the servlet.

Comment: Read more about [jstl_core_foreach_tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You would not use a declaration block to set the values but rather set them in the controller with request.setAttribute(). Then:

```
<c:forEach var="ad" items="${Products}" begin="${i}" end="${j}">
```

Comment: One more thing It should be **c:forEach** instead of **c:ForEach**. It should be **${Products}** instead of **Products**

Comment: and items="${Products}"